# Python - Looping through API and writing Dict to csv

Tags: python, api, csv, web-scraping

I am looping through an API to retrieve data for multiple ICO tokens. Now, I would like to save the data to a csv with variables in columns and 1 row for each ICO token. The basic code works, I have 2 problems: 
- entries are written only in every second line, which is quite unpractical. How can I specify not to leave rows blank? 
- the variable price is a list itself and thus saved in as a single item (with > 1 variables inside). How can I decompose the list to write one variable per column?

See my code here:

```
ICO_Wallet = '0xe8ff5c9c75deb346acac493c463c8950be03dfba', 
'0x7654915a1b82d6d2d0afc37c52af556ea8983c7e', 
'0x4DF812F6064def1e5e029f1ca858777CC98D2D81'

for index, Wallet in enumerate(ICO_Wallet) :
    Name = ICO_name[index]
    Number = ICO_No[index]

    try: 
        URL = 'http://api.ethplorer.io/getTokenInfo/' + Wallet + '?apiKey=freekey'
    except: 
        print(Wallet)

    json_obj = urlopen(URL) 
    data = json.load(json_obj)

    with open('token_data_test.csv','a') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        w.writerow(data.values())

    time.sleep(1)
```

Sample output:

```
data Out[59]: 
{'address': '0x8a854288a5976036a725879164ca3e91d30c6a1b',
 'countOps': 24207,
 'decimals': '18',
 'ethTransfersCount': 0,
 'holdersCount': 10005,
 'issuancesCount': 0,
 'lastUpdated': 1542599890,
 'name': 'GET',
 'owner': '0x9a417e4db28778b6d9a4f42a5d7d01252a3af849',
 'price': {'availableSupply': '11388258.0',
           'currency': 'USD',
           'diff': -20.71,
           'diff30d': -14.155971452386,
           'diff7d': -22.52,
           'marketCapUsd': '2814942.0',
           'rate': '0.2471792958',
           'ts': '1542641433',
           'volume24h': '2371.62380719'},
 'symbol': 'GET',
 'totalSupply': '33368773400000170376363910',
 'transfersCount': 24207}
```

Comment: What does your program print out, if anything? Could we get an example response JSON?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the site is, but it might not be wise to share your token information publicly.

Comment: Your first problem is a trivial one, you just need to add `lineterminator='\n'` as a keyword argument in your `csv.writer()`.  Your second one is less trivial and will be helpful to see some sample structure of the data.

Comment: @Idlehands: Your suggestion to the first problem worked, thank you! I uploaded a sample output above

Comment: @Idlehands: It is a public API with no personal info, so no problem here. Just like any other movie title example ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, it's an easy fix for the first problem, just modify the `csv.writer` line like this:

```
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", lineterminator='\n')
```

For your second problem, you can flatten your `json` before passing into `csv`:

```
for k, v in data.pop('price').items():
         data['price_{}'.format(k)] = v
```

This changes all items under `price` into `price_itemname` as a flattened key.  The `.pop()` method also helps remove the `'price'` key at the same time.

Result:

```
{'address': '0x8a854288a5976036a725879164ca3e91d30c6a1b',
 'countOps': 24207,
 'decimals': '18',
 'ethTransfersCount': 0,
 'holdersCount': 10005,
 'issuancesCount': 0,
 'lastUpdated': 1542599890,
 'name': 'GET',
 'owner': '0x9a417e4db28778b6d9a4f42a5d7d01252a3af849',
 'price_availableSupply': '11388258.0',
 'price_currency': 'USD',
 'price_diff': -20.71,
 'price_diff30d': -14.155971452386,
 'price_diff7d': -22.52,
 'price_marketCapUsd': '2814942.0',
 'price_rate': '0.2471792958',
 'price_ts': '1542641433',
 'price_volume24h': '2371.62380719',
 'symbol': 'GET',
 'totalSupply': '33368773400000170376363910',
 'transfersCount': 24207}
```

Now you can just pass that into your `csv.writer()`.